# How to use Erlang configuration files with Python J2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2, ansible

I would like to deploy with Ansible some configuration files the following way:

```
- name: Deploying test configuration
  template: src={{ item }}.j2 dest={{ basho_bench_home_dir }}/conf/{{ item }}
  sudo: yes
  with_items:
    - http_fix_1min.conf.template
    - http_max_1min.conf
```

The files have lines like these:

```
{mode, max}.
{duration, 1}.
{concurrent, 32}.
```

This ultimately breaks the J2 rendering:

```
fatal: [192.168.99.135] => {'msg': "AnsibleError: file: roles/basho_bench/templates/http_fix_1min.conf.template.j2, line number: 24, error: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'Content'", 'failed': True}
fatal: [192.168.99.135] => {'msg': 'One or more items failed.', 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'results': [{'msg': "AnsibleError: file: roles/basho_bench/templates/http_fix_1min.conf.template.j2, line number: 24, error: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'Content'", 'failed': True}]}
```

I am not sure how to tell J2 to handle the template as a giant string. I have tried {{' '}} as the documentation suggests. It did now work.

Comment: Can you share your `http_fix_1min.conf.template.j2` file?

Comment: Yes, https://gist.github.com/l1x/34fc89a5b0f2be9c0106

Comment: I do not see any templating in your conf. Why do you use `template` instead of [`copy`](http://docs.ansible.com/copy_module.html)?

Comment: extension of the file you posted is `.erl` not j2. So looks to me like you don't have j2 contents in your template file so use `copy` as Alik said instead of `template` which will just copy `src` to `dest`. OR do you use some variables inside your 'template'? If so then you're kinda on the right track, read the J2 documentation, not ansible.

Comment: Yes I think copy is fine. Now question follows, what happens if i need those files as templates because I would like to change the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{% raw %}`/`{% endraw %}` blocks as Jinja2 documentation [suggests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping).

Before you could override Jinja2 evironment settings by placing

```
#jinja2: variable_end_string: [[, variable_start_string: ]]
```

on the first line of a template file so that `{{ }}` weren't not treated as tags. Ansible devs have disabled this feature because of some security issues. Right now it is  still not available. Related issie on Gihub is [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10031). Follow referenced issues and pull requests on discussion about the feature.

Comment: Thanks Alik! This is very helpful. For now we moved the files into the files/ folder and using copy as you suggested.